# compiling program code written in C/C++/Python and make binary or executable for ARM or any other OS/archetecture

Tags: android, c, linux, raspberry-pi, android-emulator

So I have to decide where a program that I like to write will run. it means three things

1. Run on same OS and processor type (developed in Linux on x86-64) used the same setup for development

No question to ask

2. Make program in Linux  x86-64 and compile it to mobile phone running android (ARM instruction set requirement because what I know is android is arm based) -- so different OS and different instruction sets of compiled-to program requirement

Question how to do it. If not using any IDE. Just want to relay on makefile -- Then what I need to install on my Linux Development Machine so what I compile my C/C++/Python code with make and produce  android arm program?

3. Make program in Linux x86-64 and run on Windows on x86-64 machine.
   Question: What I will need

Also is there any compiler or emulator for development in Linux and compiling on Linux but getting produced program for Raspberry Pi.

I just want some of available options if I am developing and compiling on Linux x86-64 computer . I like opensource options. Name and few words of explanation

Answer (score 0):

> Make program in Linux x86-64 and compile it to mobile phone running android (ARM instruction set requirement because what I know is android is arm based) -- so different OS and different instruction sets of compiled-to program requirement

And a different libc. You not just have to cross compile like for example from x86_64 desktop linux for AArch64 desktop linux, you have to link against Bionic Libc.

For this you can use the NDK from android. For a makefile, you could for example use:

```
CC=aarch64-linux-android30-clang make target (You have to change linked and ar tool and so on)
```

> Make program in Linux x86-64 and run on Windows on x86-64 machine. Question: What I will need

Use for example mingw. For debian-like, I use this packages: `mingw-w64-x86-64-dev, gcc-mingw-w64, gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix, gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix, gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32-runtime, gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32` (Some may be redundant)